# Parsing json file with nested objects

Tags: json, linux, parsing, jq

I'd like to ask you for a help.

I'm fighting with the "jq" parser but running out of ideas. I would need to extract only the needed lines from the given json file.

Here is my file:

```
{
  "SystemInventory": {
    "BIOS": [
      {
        "BIOSReleaseDate": "11/12/2020",
        "FQDD": "BIOS.Setup.1-1",
        "SMBIOSPresent": "True",
        "VersionString": "2.10.0"
      }
    ],
    "CPU": [
      {
        "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
        "Characteristics": "64-bit capable",
        "CurrentClockSpeed": "2.2 GHz",
        "DeviceDescription": "CPU 1"
      },
      {
        "CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)",
        "Characteristics": "64-bit capable",
        "CurrentClockSpeed": "2.2 GHz",
        "DeviceDescription": "CPU 2"
      }
    ],
    "iDRACNIC": [
      {
        "IPv4Address": "6.6.16.16",
        "NICDuplex": "Full",
        "NICEnabled": "Enabled",
        "NICSpeed": "100",
        "PermanentMACAddress": "5c:d8:8f:1e:51:ce"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would need only some lines let's say, I would expect the output like this:

```
"BIOSReleaseDate": "11/12/2020"
"VersionString": "2.10.0"
"CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)"
"DeviceDescription": "CPU 1"
"DeviceDescription": "CPU 2"
"IPv4Address": "6.6.16.16"
"NICSpeed": "100"
```

I tried it with "jq" parser but when it comes to nested objects I'm out of ideas.
Is there a way how can I achieve this via jq?

I would appreciate any kind of help..

Many thanks in advance

The following approach how to parse the specific rows, based on your inputs, seems to be more convenient for me:

```
cat data.json | jq '.SystemInventory.BIOS[0] | {BIOS: .VersionString}'
{
  "BIOS": "2.10.0"
}
```

and

```
cat data.json | jq '.SystemInventory.iDRACNIC[0] | {IP: .IPv4Address}'
{
  "IP": "6.6.16.16"
}
```

Is there a way how to achieve that in one command?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to show the code you use for simpler cases.

Comment: What's wrong with `jq '.SystemInventory.BIOS[0].BIOSReleaseDate'` and so on?

Comment: In the absence of both a description of the requirements and some kind of code or pseudo-code, it's very difficult to discern requirements from a single example of input and expected output!

Answer (score 0):

With your sample, the following invocation produces the output shown below in accordance with what I take to be the requirements, though the output does slightly differ from what is shown in the question:

```
jq -r -f program.jq myfile.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
.SystemInventory[][]
| {BIOSReleaseDate, VersionString, CPUFamily, DeviceDescription, IPv4Address, NICSpeed}
| to_entries[]
| select(.value != null)
| "\"\(.key)\": \"\(.value)\""
```

#### Output

```
"BIOSReleaseDate": "11/12/2020"
"VersionString": "2.10.0"
"CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)"
"DeviceDescription": "CPU 1"
"CPUFamily": "Intel(R) Xeon(TM)"
"DeviceDescription": "CPU 2"
"IPv4Address": "6.6.16.16"
"NICSpeed": "100"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I need to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

`jq '.SystemInventory.BIOS[0].BIOSReleaseDate'` seems to be fine but I will get just one row, and how to combine with other one e.g. `jq '.SystemInventory.iDRACNIC[0].IPv4Address'` so I would get two lines as output??
thanks